# Xubuntu 12.04 keyboard freezes but only in x

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu

I'm new to xubuntu (only because my laptop won't run any modern linux flavour).[pentium m] 
Randomly I would get a keyboard hang up - no warning. (when i say this, a couple of times the menu also did not work)
The mouse still works and if I switch to another tty, the keyboard works fine.
from here I can run an init 6 to reboot the system and all is well again.

I have noticed that it is more prone to happen when I use the keyboad shotcuts on my laptop, for instance fn+vol up or fn+vol down.

I have not installed proprietary ati drivers nor changed keymappings. 
updated or unupdated, it does the dame thing. (I have now installed 12 times)

attached is my hardinfo:

Devices

---

### Processor

```
-Processor-
Name        : Intel(R) Pentium(R) M processor 1.60GHz
Family, model, stepping     : 6, 13, 6 (Pentium III/Pentium III Xeon/Celeron)
Vendor      : Intel
-Configuration-
Cache Size      : 2048kb
Frequency       : 1600.00MHz
BogoMIPS        : 3191.88
Byte Order      : Little Endian
-Features-
FDIV Bug        : no
HLT Bug     : no
F00F Bug        : no
Coma Bug        : no
Has FPU     : yes
-Cache-
Cache information not available
-Capabilities-
fpu     : Floating Point Unit
vme     : Virtual 86 Mode Extension
de      : Debug Extensions - I/O breakpoints
pse     : Page Size Extensions (4MB pages)
tsc     : Time Stamp Counter and RDTSC instruction
msr     : Model Specific Registers
mce     : Machine Check Architeture
cx8     : CMPXCHG8 instruction
mtrr        : Memory Type Range Registers
pge     : Page Global Enable
mca     : Machine Check Architecture
cmov        : Conditional Move instruction
clflush     : Cache Line Flush instruction
dts     : Debug Store
acpi        : Thermal Monitor and Software Controlled Clock
mmx     : MMX technology
fxsr        : FXSAVE and FXRSTOR instructions
sse     : SSE instructions
sse2        : SSE2 (WNI) instructions
ss      : Self Snoop
tm      : Thermal Monitor
pbe     : Pending Break Enable
up      : smp kernel running on up
bts     : Branch Trace Store
est     : Enhanced SpeedStep
tm2     : Thermal Monitor 2
```

### Memory

```
-Memory-
Total Memory        : 2061876 kB
Free Memory     : 744036 kB
Buffers     : 91920 kB
Cached      : 772060 kB
Cached Swap     : 0 kB
Active      : 678124 kB
Inactive        : 562704 kB
Active(anon)        : 377544 kB
Inactive(anon)      : 5176 kB
Active(file)        : 300580 kB
Inactive(file)      : 557528 kB
Unevictable     : 0 kB
Mlocked     : 0 kB
High Memory     : 1187784 kB
Free High Memory        : 77984 kB
Low Memory      : 874092 kB
Free Low Memory     : 666052 kB
Virtual Memory      : 2096124 kB
Free Virtual Memory     : 2096124 kB
Dirty       : 168 kB
Writeback       : 0 kB
AnonPages       : 376860 kB
Mapped      : 91404 kB
Shmem       : 5840 kB
Slab        : 48688 kB
SReclaimable        : 36984 kB
SUnreclaim      : 11704 kB
KernelStack     : 2536 kB
PageTables      : 6524 kB
NFS_Unstable        : 0 kB
Bounce      : 0 kB
WritebackTmp        : 0 kB
CommitLimit     : 3127060 kB
Committed_AS        : 1731096 kB
VmallocTotal        : 122880 kB
VmallocUsed     : 10704 kB
VmallocChunk        : 109088 kB
HardwareCorrupted       : 0 kB
AnonHugePages       : 0 kB
HugePages_Total     : 0
HugePages_Free      : 0
HugePages_Rsvd      : 0
HugePages_Surp      : 0
Hugepagesize        : 4096 kB
DirectMap4k     : 32760 kB
DirectMap4M     : 876544 kB
```

### PCI Devices

```
-PCI Devices-
Host bridge     : Intel Corporation 82852/82855 GM/GME/PM/GMV Processor to I/O Controller (rev 02)
System peripheral       : Intel Corporation 82852/82855 GM/GME/PM/GMV Processor to I/O Controller (rev 02)
System peripheral       : Intel Corporation 82852/82855 GM/GME/PM/GMV Processor to I/O Controller (rev 02)
PCI bridge      : Intel Corporation 82852/82855 GM/GME/PM/GMV Processor to AGP Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
USB controller      : Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
USB controller      : Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
USB controller      : Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-M) USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
PCI bridge      : Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 83) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
ISA bridge      : Intel Corporation 82801DBM (ICH4-M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 03)
IDE interface       : Intel Corporation 82801DBM (ICH4-M) IDE Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 8a [Master SecP PriP])
SMBus       : Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
Multimedia audio controller     : Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 03)
Modem       : Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) AC'97 Modem Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Generic])
VGA compatible controller       : Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV350 [Mobility Radeon 9600 M10] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Network controller      : Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 2200BG [Calexico2] Network Connection (rev 05)
Ethernet controller     : Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ (rev 10)
CardBus bridge      : ENE Technology Inc CB-710/2/4 Cardbus Controller (rev 01)
FLASH memory        : ENE Technology Inc CB710 Memory Card Reader Controller
FireWire (IEEE 1394)        : VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6306/7/8 [Fire II(M)] IEEE 1394 OHCI Controller (rev 80) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
```

### USB Devices

### Printers

```
-Printers-
No printers found
```

### Battery

```
-Battery: BAT0-
State       : charged (load: 0 mA)
Capacity        : 0 mAh / 0 mAh (-nan%)
Battery Technology      : rechargeable (Lion)
Model Number        : Internal Battery
Serial Number
```

### Sensors

### Input Devices

```
-Input Devices-
 Sleep Button
 Lid Switch
 Power Button
 AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
 SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
```

### Storage

```
-SCSI Disks-
ATA Hitachi HTS54168
TSSTcorp CD/DVDW SN-S082D
HUAWEI Mass Storage
HUAWEI TF CARD Storage
 USB FLASH DRIVE
```

### DMI

```
-BIOS-
Date        : 12/01/2004
Vendor      : Insyde Software Corporation
Version     : R1.10
-Board-
Name        : Montara-GML
Vendor      : MTC
```

### Resources

```
-I/O Ports-
<tt>0000-001f </tt>     : dma1
<tt>0020-0021 </tt>     : pic1
<tt>0040-0043 </tt>     : timer0
<tt>0050-0053 </tt>     : timer1
<tt>0060-0060 </tt>     : keyboard
<tt>0062-0062 </tt>     : EC data
<tt>0064-0064 </tt>     : keyboard
<tt>0066-0066 </tt>     : EC cmd
<tt>0070-0077 </tt>     : rtc0
<tt>0080-008f </tt>     : dma page reg
<tt>00a0-00a1 </tt>     : pic2
<tt>00c0-00df </tt>     : dma2
<tt>00f0-00ff </tt>     : fpu
<tt>0170-0177 </tt>     : Intel Corporation 82801DBM (ICH4-M) IDE Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 8a [Master SecP PriP])
<tt>  0170-0177 </tt>       : ata_piix
<tt>01f0-01f7 </tt>     : Intel Corporation 82801DBM (ICH4-M) IDE Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 8a [Master SecP PriP])
<tt>  01f0-01f7 </tt>       : ata_piix
<tt>0200-020f </tt>     : pnp 00:07
<tt>0290-0297 </tt>     : pnp 00:07
<tt>0376-0376 </tt>     : Intel Corporation 82801DBM (ICH4-M) IDE Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 8a [Master SecP PriP])
<tt>  0376-0376 </tt>       : ata_piix
<tt>03f6-03f6 </tt>     : Intel Corporation 82801DBM (ICH4-M) IDE Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 8a [Master SecP PriP])
<tt>  03f6-03f6 </tt>       : ata_piix
<tt>0680-06ff </tt>     : pnp 00:07
<tt>077c-077f </tt>     : pnp 00:07
<tt>0cf8-0cff </tt>     : PCI conf1
<tt>1000-107f </tt>     : Intel Corporation 82801DBM (ICH4-M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 03)
<tt>  1000-107f </tt>       : pnp 00:07
<tt>    1000-1003 </tt>     : ACPI PM1a_EVT_BLK
<tt>    1004-1005 </tt>     : ACPI PM1a_CNT_BLK
<tt>    1008-100b </tt>     : ACPI PM_TMR
<tt>    1010-1015 </tt>     : ACPI CPU throttle
<tt>    1020-1020 </tt>     : ACPI PM2_CNT_BLK
<tt>    1028-102f </tt>     : ACPI GPE0_BLK
<tt>1100-110f </tt>     : Intel Corporation 82801DBM (ICH4-M) IDE Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 8a [Master SecP PriP])
<tt>  1100-110f </tt>       : ata_piix
<tt>1200-121f </tt>     : Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
<tt>  1200-121f </tt>       : uhci_hcd
<tt>1300-133f </tt>     : Intel Corporation 82801DBM (ICH4-M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 03)
<tt>  1300-133f </tt>       : pnp 00:07
<tt>1400-141f </tt>     : Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
<tt>1600-161f </tt>     : Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
<tt>  1600-161f </tt>       : uhci_hcd
<tt>a000-bfff </tt>     : PCI Bus 0000:02
<tt>  a000-a07f </tt>       : VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6306/7/8 [Fire II(M)] IEEE 1394 OHCI Controller (rev 80) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
<tt>  a080-a0ff </tt>       : ENE Technology Inc CB710 Memory Card Reader Controller
<tt>    a080-a0ff </tt>     : ENE CB710 memory card reader driver
<tt>  a200-a2ff </tt>       : Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ (rev 10)
<tt>    a200-a2ff </tt>     : RealTek RTL-8139 Fast Ethernet driver
<tt>  a400-a4ff </tt>       : PCI CardBus 0000:03
<tt>  a800-a8ff </tt>       : PCI CardBus 0000:03
<tt>c000-dfff </tt>     : PCI Bus 0000:01
<tt>  c100-c1ff </tt>       : Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV350 [Mobility Radeon 9600 M10] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
<tt>e000-e0ff </tt>     : Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 03)
<tt>  e000-e0ff </tt>       : Intel 82801DB-ICH4
<tt>e100-e13f </tt>     : Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 03)
<tt>  e100-e13f </tt>       : Intel 82801DB-ICH4
<tt>e200-e2ff </tt>     : Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) AC'97 Modem Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Generic])
<tt>e300-e37f </tt>     : Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) AC'97 Modem Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Generic])
-Memory-
<tt>00000000-0000ffff </tt>     : reserved
<tt>00010000-0009fbff </tt>     : System RAM
<tt>0009fc00-0009ffff </tt>     : reserved
<tt>000a0000-000bffff </tt>     : Video RAM area
<tt>000c0000-000cffff </tt>     : Video ROM
<tt>000e0000-000fffff </tt>     : reserved
<tt>  000e0000-000e17ff </tt>       : Adapter ROM
<tt>  000f0000-000fffff </tt>       : System ROM
<tt>00100000-7ffeffff </tt>     : System RAM
<tt>  01000000-0157be03 </tt>       : Kernel code
<tt>  0157be04-0182f57f </tt>       : Kernel data
<tt>  018e8000-019bffff </tt>       : Kernel bss
<tt>7fff0000-7fffffbf </tt>     : ACPI Tables
<tt>7fffffc0-7fffffff </tt>     : ACPI Non-volatile Storage
<tt>80000000-800003ff </tt>     : Intel Corporation 82801DBM (ICH4-M) IDE Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 8a [Master SecP PriP])
<tt>90000000-9fffffff </tt>     : PCI Bus 0000:02
<tt>  90000000-93ffffff </tt>       : PCI CardBus 0000:03
<tt>a0000000-afffffff </tt>     : PCI Bus 0000:01
<tt>  a0000000-a001ffff </tt>       : Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV350 [Mobility Radeon 9600 M10] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
<tt>  a8000000-afffffff </tt>       : Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV350 [Mobility Radeon 9600 M10] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
<tt>b0000000-bfffffff </tt>     : Intel Corporation 82852/82855 GM/GME/PM/GMV Processor to I/O Controller (rev 02)
<tt>d0000000-dfffffff </tt>     : PCI Bus 0000:02
<tt>  d0000000-d00007ff </tt>       : VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6306/7/8 [Fire II(M)] IEEE 1394 OHCI Controller (rev 80) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
<tt>    d0000000-d00007ff </tt>     : Driver for PCI OHCI IEEE1394 controllers
<tt>  d0000800-d00008ff </tt>       : Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ (rev 10)
<tt>    d0000800-d00008ff </tt>     : RealTek RTL-8139 Fast Ethernet driver
<tt>  d0001000-d0001fff </tt>       : Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 2200BG [Calexico2] Network Connection (rev 05)
<tt>    d0001000-d0001fff </tt>     : Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 2200/2915 Network Driver
<tt>  d4000000-d4000fff </tt>       : ENE Technology Inc CB-710/2/4 Cardbus Controller (rev 01)
<tt>    d4000000-d4000fff </tt>     : yenta_socket
<tt>  d8000000-dbffffff </tt>       : PCI CardBus 0000:03
<tt>e0000000-efffffff </tt>     : PCI Bus 0000:01
<tt>  e0010000-e001ffff </tt>       : Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV350 [Mobility Radeon 9600 M10] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
<tt>f0000400-f00005ff </tt>     : Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 03)
<tt>  f0000400-f00005ff </tt>       : Intel 82801DB-ICH4
<tt>f0000600-f00006ff </tt>     : Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 03)
<tt>  f0000600-f00006ff </tt>       : Intel 82801DB-ICH4
<tt>febff000-febff3ff </tt>     : Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-M) USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
<tt>  febff000-febff3ff </tt>       : ehci_hcd
<tt>ffb80000-ffbfffff </tt>     : reserved
<tt>fff80000-ffffffff </tt>     : reserved
<tt>  fff80000-ffffffff </tt>       : pnp 00:05
-DMA-
<tt> 4</tt>     : cascade
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues on a similar Centrino M laptop a while ago:

- total blackout when using the fn keys to dim the LCD panel
- total lockup when using the fn keys to query the battery level.

It seemed to me that these functions were hardwired into the BIOS and only tested with Windows. The workaround at the time was to append the kernel command line with NOAPIC NOLAPIC, ymmv.